# Convert row with columns of data into column with multiple rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I hv rows of data:-

```
TAG   SKU   SIZE   GRADE   LOCATION
A001  123    12      A       X1
A002  789    13      B       X3
A003  456    15      C       X5
```

I need to convert it into:-

```
A001   123  SIZE 12
A001   123  GRADE A
A001   123  LOCATION X1
A002   789  SIZE 13
A002   789  GRADE B
A002   789  LOCATION X3
A003   456  SIZE 15
A003   456  GRADE C
A003   456  LOCATION X5
```

I used the below (based on Ben McCormack's suggestion posted on Nov 23 '09) but it doesn't produce the above result :-

```
Sub NormalizeSheet()
Dim wsOriginal As Worksheet
Dim wsNormalized As Worksheet
Dim strKey As String
Dim clnHeader As Collection
Dim lngColumnCounter As Long
Dim lngRowCounterOriginal As Long
Dim lngRowCounterNormalized As Long
Dim rngCurrent As Range
Dim varColumn As Variant

Set wsOriginal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Original")     'This is the name of your original worksheet'
Set wsNormalized = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Normalized") 'This is the name of the new worksheet'
Set clnHeader = New Collection

wsNormalized.Cells.ClearContents        'This deletes the contents of the destination worksheet'

lngColumnCounter = 2
lngRowCounterOriginal = 1
Set rngCurrent = wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter)

' We'll loop through just the headers to get a collection of header names'
Do Until IsEmpty(rngCurrent.Value)
    clnHeader.Add rngCurrent.Value, CStr(lngColumnCounter)
    lngColumnCounter = lngColumnCounter + 1
    Set rngCurrent = wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter)
Loop

'Here we'll reset our Row Counter and loop through the entire data set'
lngRowCounterOriginal = 2
lngRowCounterNormalized = 1
lngColumnCounter = 1

Do While Not IsEmpty(wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter))

    Set rngCurrent = wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter)
    strKey = rngCurrent.Value ' Get the key value from the current cell'
    lngColumnCounter = 2

    'This next loop parses the denormalized values for each row'
    Do While Not IsEmpty(wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter))
        Set rngCurrent = wsOriginal.Cells(lngRowCounterOriginal, lngColumnCounter)

        'We're going to check to see if the current value'
        'is equal to NULL. If it is, we won't add it to'
        'the Normalized Table.'
        If rngCurrent.Value = "NULL" Then
            'Skip it'
        Else
            'Add this item to the normalized sheet'
            wsNormalized.Range("A" & lngRowCounterNormalized).Value = strKey
            wsNormalized.Range("B" & lngRowCounterNormalized).Value = clnHeader(CStr(lngColumnCounter))
            wsNormalized.Range("C" & lngRowCounterNormalized).Value = rngCurrent.Value
            lngRowCounterNormalized = lngRowCounterNormalized + 1
        End If

        lngColumnCounter = lngColumnCounter + 1
    Loop
    lngRowCounterOriginal = lngRowCounterOriginal + 1
    lngColumnCounter = 1    'We reset the column counter here because we're on a new row'
Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: You can convert the Excel file to a CSV and do the logic in your favorite language

Comment: Bob, you've got a bunch of people helping you build various parts of your project and you haven't accepted or voted up a single answer. How about giving us a little credit?

Comment: More than happy to do so but where or how can I do that ?

Comment: Everything is explained in the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: "vote up requires 15 reputation"... guess i'm still pretty new.

Comment: Thanks. It's all part of the process. I'm new myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach going from worksheet to worksheet directly. This might be necessary if the dataset is too big and available memory too small for using arrays. It's likely to be slow.

It uses the same call parameters as reOrgV1, and pretty much the same logic.

It's updated to add "DEFECTS" to the properies. The input looks like:

```
TAG     SKU   SIZE GRADE LOCATION DEFECTS
A001    123    12   A       X1      3
A002    789    13   B       X3      5
A003    456    15   C       X5      7
```

Here's the code.

```
Public Sub reOrgV2(inSource As Range, inTarget As Range)
'' This version works directly on the worksheet
'' and transfers the result directly to the target
'' given as the top-left cell of the result.

'' **** Changed to add "Defects"
    Dim resNames()
    Dim propNum As Integer
    Dim srcRows As Integer
    Dim resRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim g As Integer

    '' Shape the result
    resNames = Array("Size", "Grade", "Location", "Defects")
    propNum = 1 + UBound(resNames)

    '' Row counts
    srcRows = inSource.Rows.Count
    resRows = srcRows * propNum

    '' re-org and transfer source to result range
    inTarget = inTarget.Resize(resRows, 4)
    g = 1
    For i = 1 To srcRows
        For j = 0 To 3
            inTarget.Item(g + j, 1) = inSource.Item(i, 1)      '' Tag
            inTarget.Item(g + j, 2) = inSource.Item(i, 2)      '' SKU
            inTarget.Item(g + j, 3) = resNames(j)              '' Property
            inTarget.Item(g + j, 4) = inSource.Item(i, j + 3)  '' Value
        Next j
        g = g + propNum
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is the revised call sourcing the wider range.

```
'' Call ReOrgV2 with input and output ranges
Public Sub test4()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = Range("InData!A:A").Find("").Row - 2
    reOrgV2 Range("InData!A2").Resize(i, 6), [OutData!A1]
End Sub
```

Comment: For reOrgV1, it stopped after the 3rd row of InData. For reOrgV2, I rcv'd Run-time error '13': Type mismatch with inTarget.Item(g + j, 2) = Int(inSource.Item(i, 2)) highlighted.

Comment: Great, both are working. However, the output needs to be adjusted to Column A for TAG, Column B for SKU, Column C for Size,Grade,Location & Column D for 12,A,X1. Current output has 3 columns & I need to present it in 4 columns.

Comment: BTW, how can i start the conversion without defining the ranges ? U see, some of the InData files may hv just 2 rows & some, a few thousand rows. So, it's kinda tedious to keep adjusting the ranges before I can perform the conversion.

Comment: Added the size input array & it prompted with Run-time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed with Range("InData!A2").Select highlighted.

Comment: Added test3() & it prompted with Run-time error '424: Object required with reOrgV2 Range("InData!A2").Resize(i, 5), [OutData!A1] highlighted.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. It works. I hv to remove test2() 1st & then go with test3() only. Thanks.

Comment: What if i wish to add in an extra row for eg. TAG, SKU, SIZE, GRADE,  LOCATION & DEFECTS. Where or how shd I amend it ?

Comment: You'll need to add "Defects" to resNames, fix the srcRows, resRows and g settings, add a line to the "For j = 0 .." loop, fix the resize in test3(). I think that catches it.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it to run. Can u add those changes to the above script ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADO with Excel. Roughly:

```
Sub ColsToRows()
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim s As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    ''This is not the best way to refer to the workbook
    ''you want, but it is very convenient for notes
    ''It is probably best to use the name of the workbook.

    strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    ''Note that if HDR=No, F1,F2 etc are used for column names,
    ''if HDR=Yes, the names in the first row of the range
    ''can be used.
    ''This is the Jet 4 connection string, you can get more
    ''here : http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

     strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Docs\TestBook.xls " _
            & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    ''Late binding, so no reference is needed

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")


    cn.Open strCon

    strSQL = "SELECT [TAG], [SKU], 'SIZE ' & [SIZE] As S, " _
           & "'GRADE ' & [GRADE] As G, 'LOCATION ' & [LOCATION] As L " _
           & "FROM [Sheet1$] a " _
           & "ORDER BY [Tag] "

    rs.Open strSQL, cn, 3, 3


    ''Pick a suitable empty worksheet for the results

    With Worksheets("Sheet3")

        j = 1 '' Row counter

        Do While Not rs.EOF
            For i = 2 To 4
                .Cells(j, 1) = rs!Tag
                .Cells(j, 2) = rs!SKU
                .Cells(j, 3) = rs(i)
                j = j + 1
            Next
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

   ''Tidy up
   rs.Close
   Set rs = Nothing
   cn.Close
   Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the above & prompted with Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Invalid argument with cn.Open strCon highlighted.

Comment: Once again, fairly standard VBA seems to be causing problems for you, so I wonder which version of Excel are you using? What is your operating system?

Comment: Okay, what both these problems have in common seems to be the active sheet or workbook. I have edited the strCon line to refer to the name of a workbook, please change it to refer to the full name and path for the test workbook.

Comment: One more thing occurs to me, what is your locale?

Comment: Locale is similar to country and setting the locale for an application  or computer determines things like currency delimiters (, or .) and also some odd bits and pieces in VBA.

Comment: In that case, it's Singapore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really simple solution that assumes the dataset isn't huge. It takes the input range into an array, transforms it into a result array, then moves the array to the specified target. The target is defined by the top left cell.

When it's possible, this approach is orders of magnitude faster than working directly with cells on worksheets.

The test function at the bottom needs you to put an input set on sheet InData and have a sheet OutData defined for the results but your input and output ranges can be anywhere you want.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub reOrgV1(inSource As Range, inTarget As Range)
'' This version uses VBA arrays to do the work.
'' Takes a source range, reorganizes it to the target
''    given as the top-left cell of the result.

    Dim srcArray As Variant
    Dim resArray As Variant
    Dim resNames()
    resNames = Array("SIZE", "GRADE", "LOCATION")

    Dim srcRows As Integer
    Dim resRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim g As Integer

    '' Move range into source array
    srcArray = inSource.Value
    srcRows = UBound(srcArray, 1)
    resRows = srcRows * 3

    ''Build result array
    ReDim resArray(1 To resRows, 1 To 3)

    '' transfer source to result array
    g = 1
    For i = 1 To srcRows
        For j = 0 To 2
            resArray(g + j, 1) = srcArray(i, 1)
            resArray(g + j, 2) = srcArray(i, 2)
            resArray(g + j, 3) = resNames(j) & " " & srcArray(i, j + 3)
        Next j
        g = g + 3
    Next i

    '' Move the results to the target range
    inTarget.Resize(resRows, 3).Value = resArray
End Sub

Public Sub test1()
    reOrgV1 Range("InData!A2:E4"), Range("OutData!A1")
End Sub
```