# With Excel VBA Create Multiple Rows From One Row

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel sheet (InData) which has individual rows of data by unique "ID NUMBER".  Each ID Number may have multiple "deductions" and "benefits" contained in the one row. But I need to convert the single row of data into multiple rows by ID Number and write the results into a new sheet (OutData).

I tried to attach my sample Excel file but can't find way to do it.  So attached sample images for InData and OutData.

This is InData...
[image]

This is OuData...
[image]

Below is code I'm using.

```
Option Explicit
'Found original VBA here...
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698442/convert-row-with-columns-of-data-into-column-with-multiple-rows-in-excel

Sub reOrgV2_New(inSource As Range, inTarget As Range)
'' This version works directly on the worksheet
'' and transfers the result directly to the target
'' given as the top-left cell of the result.

    Dim resNames()
    Dim propNum As Integer
    Dim srcRows As Integer
    Dim resRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim g As Integer

    '' Shape the result
    resNames = Array("Deduction Desc", "Deduction Amount", "Deduction Start Date", "Deduction Stop Date", _
    "Benefit Desc", "Benefit Amount", "Benefit Start Date", "Benefit Stop Date")
    propNum = 1 + UBound(resNames)

    '' Row counts
    srcRows = inSource.Rows.Count
    resRows = srcRows * propNum

    '' re-org and transfer source to result range
     inTarget = inTarget.Resize(resRows, 7)

    g = 1
    For i = 1 To srcRows
        For j = 0 To 7
            inTarget.Item(g + j, 1) = inSource.Item(i, 1)      '' ID NUMBER
            inTarget.Item(g + j, 2) = inSource.Item(i, 2)      '' LAST NAME
            inTarget.Item(g + j, 3) = inSource.Item(i, 3)      '' FIRST NAME
            inTarget.Item(g + j, 4) = resNames(j)              '' Column Type
            inTarget.Item(g + j, 5) = inSource.Item(i, j + 4)  '' Value
        Next j
        g = g + propNum
    Next i
End Sub
'' Call ReOrgV2_New with input and output ranges
Sub ReOrg_New()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    i = Range("InData!A:A").Find("").Row - 2
    reOrgV2_New Range("InData!A2").Resize(i, 7), [OutData!A2]

    With Sheets("OutData")
        'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
        .Select

        '' apply column headings and autofit/align
        .Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("ID NUMBER", "LAST NAME", "FIRST NAME", "Column Type", "Value")
        .Columns("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Columns("E:E").HorizontalAlignment = xlRight

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Does your code not work at all? Does it work, just not as you expect? Does it error somewhere (if so, where and what error)?

Comment: Bruce, the code works but it does not generate desired output as shown in OutData image.

Answer (score 0):

Pertinent to your task definition, it seems that you can achieve the result simply by deletion of the unnecessary Worksheet Columns, which could be performed as, for example: `Columns("H").Delete`, or `Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete` and so on (see the following sample VBA code snippet):

```
Sub DeleteColumns()

    'delete columns
    Columns("AR:AU").Delete
    Columns("H:AL").Delete

    ' re-arrange columns order
    Columns("D").Cut
    Columns("F").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```

Then you can just re-arrange the order of residual data columns.

Hope this may help.